# What parts do I need to connect a CO2 bulb to a normal regulator

Tags: carbonation

I have a portable keg system that a dip tube assembly that has a gas in post, that can take a CO2 feed from a standard regulator.

These units often come with these tiny regulators that accept CO2 bulbs, but they are rubbish at maintaining a useful dispense pressure.

So if I have a normal regulator how would I connect one of those CO2 bulbs to it? Any parts I should get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something called a puncture device

[image]

This link has both for threaded and non threaded cartridges. 
[Leland Limited](http://www.lelandltd.com/puncture_devices.htm)

FYI, these devices are not regulated, and can be dangerous if directions are not followed.